# if exists, update else insert, with cursors in stored procedures returns only 1 row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I have 2 tables api(columns - api , api_context, api_id -->primary key) and api_request_summary(columns - api_context). i need to insert the number of times the api_context relevant to a particular api_id is repeated in the table curhittest1. That is I need to get the count of how many times a value in the column api_context is repeated and insert it with the api_id. Both tables have multiple rows so i have used cursors to loop through the tables. i can correctly insert the values to the table but i need to check whether that api_id already exists in the curhittest1 table and if yes update and if no insert.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE curhit12()

BEGIN

 DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
 DECLARE apiId, noOfHits int(11);
 Declare apiContext varchar(255);

 DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR Select api_id from api;

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;     

  OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO apiId;

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF; 

    select api_context into apiContext from api where api_id =apiId;  

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM api_request_summary WHERE api_context=apiContext into noOfHits;

 IF exists (SELECT * FROM curhittest1 WHERE apiid = apiId) THEN

   UPDATE curhittest1
                      SET noofhits=noOfHits                        
                      WHERE apiid = apiId;
 ELSE

  insert into curhittest1(apiid,noofhits) values (apiId,noOfHits);
 END IF;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;

END//
DELIMITER
```

When I use the following code only 1 row is added to the curhittest1 table. When the exact same code is used in sql procedures without cursors it displays so i'm assuming i need to do something differently when using with cursors. How can i add all the values to the table accurately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after using INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. For anyone interested here is the code

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE curhit12()

BEGIN

 DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
 DECLARE apiId, noOfHits int(11);
 Declare apiContext varchar(255);    
 DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR Select api_id from api;    
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;     

  OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO apiId;

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF; 

    select api_context into apiContext from api where api_id =apiId;  

SET noOfHits = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM api_request_summary 
                WHERE api_context=apiContext);

INSERT INTO api_hits (api_id,no_of_hits) VALUES (apiId,noOfHits)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE no_of_hits=noOfHits;

  END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;

END//
DELIMITER
```

Answer (score 0):

The second `INTO` sentence inside loop maybe trigger the `NOT FOUND` handler.

Change this line:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM api_request_summary WHERE api_context=apiContext into noOfHits;
```

To this:

```
SET noOfHits = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM api_request_summary 
                WHERE api_context=apiContext);
```